# ¿Cómo puedo guardar los cambios en mi branch y cambiarme a otra branch sin tener que hacer commit?

Tags: git

Es posible que yo tenga varios *branch*

```
--develop
---foo
---bar
```

Y por ejemplo, yo tengo cambios en `foo`, pero quiero pasarme a `bar`, pero **SIN** hacer *commit* de los cambios en `foo`, hay alguna forma de guardarlos "temporalmente" sin necesidad que aparezcan en la historia de los *commits*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes usar `git stash` para subir los cambios a los que no les hayas hecho `commit`, luego pasarte a otro `branch` y cuando hayas terminado en ese otro `branch` de hacer lo que tenías que hacer, puedes regresar al `branch` original y hacer `git stash apply`.

El flujo sería así:

- Estás en en `branch develop` y tienes cambios no `comiteados`
- `git stash`
- `git checkout master`
- Haces lo que tengas que hacer en master
- `git checkout develop`
- `git stash apply`
- Todo queda en `develop` como si nada hubiera pasado

Más información sobre [git stash acá](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: Curiosa palabra: 'comitear'.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` es la utilidad que más te puede ayudar para esta tarea. Diciendo

```
git stash -u
```

Los cambios que no has añadido a ningún `commit` quedarán guardados. Una vez hecho esto, puedes cambiar de `branch`, etc.

Cuando vuelvas a la `branch` original, escribiendo lo siguiente volverás a tener esos archivos presentes:

```
git stash pop
```

---

Si en algún momento te preguntas qué tienes en "stash", puedes escribir

```
git stash list
```

Y tendrás una información del tipo:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on foo: 557af3e Moviendo archivos
stash@{1}: WIP on develop: 6d8d8e0 Actualizando drivers
```